# How to call a jquery function on an event?

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, jsf

I want to display a popup window whenever an event (say some timeout occurs at server) occurs. For the popup window I am using jQuery in JSF pages (JSF 2.0). How do I call a jQuery function from a service method of a JSF ManagedBean?

Actually it's like reverse of AJAX instead of client making periodic calls to the server. I want the server to notify the client whenever some event occurs. Not all the users will have notifications all the time. I want to reduce the network calls. The server tells the client from his side that "Mr. X, this is a notification for you ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to tie Java and jQuery together, simply define your jQuery call such that, **unless** it gets a response within a certain time frame, it will display a "server is being slow" message, or some other appropriate alert.

In other words (example):

1. You do an ajax call, and while you're waiting you're displaying "Loading..." or some message
2. **By default**, if the ajax call doesn't receive a response within a defined timeout (say 5 seconds), it will automatically display, "Sorry, we're still waiting...", or whatever is appropriate for your app
3. If the ajax call **does** get a response in time, the user will simply never see the "Sorry, we're still waiting..." message, because the page will be updated with the results

Comment: @normalocity : act I want jQuery to display a popup window to the user  whenever some other user invites him. I think the options  I have are jQuery, JavaScript or JSF. Can you suggest me how to do this ? thanks buddy for ur help...

Comment: Hm, well that's implementation specific, but basically what you'll want to do is use jQuery to periodically make a call to check for new events, and if it finds one, then display the alert. One way to do this is to wrap it in an ajax call (Google for "jquery ajax()"), and update the DOM appropriately. Your question sounds more like a question around understanding how to utilize ajax for this kind of stuff. Is that correct, or am I missing your question still?

Comment: @normalocity : actually its like reverse of AJAX instead of client making periodic calls to the server. I want the server to notify the client whenever some event occurs.. not all the users will have notifications all the time. I want to reduce the network calls. The server tells the client from his side that "Mr. X, this is a notification for you ".... hope the question is now clear. isnt it ?

Comment: Well, I get that the behavior that you want is like a "push notification" rather than a periodic polling, but the server doesn't directly interact with the browser, nor can it control the browser directly via an event system like the one you describe, so that's not really possible. You can space out your periodic polling to a large time interval (say once per minute), in order to minimize traffic.

Comment: The only other way I know of doing this is to use a "hanging request", which basically makes an ajax call, but rather than returning "I have nothing new", the call simply waits until there IS something to report, and only returns at that stage. The upside is that only necessary traffic is communicated. The downside to this is that it increases the number of concurrent open connections to your server. Depending on your use case, this may be just fine. One way or another, you have to shoehorn your desired functionality into the client/server request/response structure that runs everything.

Comment: Oh, and the reason that the "hanging request" has a downside, is because each of those open connections eats up resources (most notably RAM) on your web server. Like I said, depending on your use case, such as the average/peak number of users that might have a hanging request open at any time, and the amount of RAM available, this might not be a problem. It's just an FYI for your implementation.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I think this hanging request method may work for me, Can the number of concurrent connections be reduced by introducing optimum time intervals ?...hope that will work.

Comment: Sure, you can strike a balance between the two by specifying a large timeout on the hanging request (say 20 minutes). When the timeout is reached, the connection is freed up, and those resources are made available for other connections. How long your timeout should be will depend on (1) your available RAM, and (2) the number of simultaneous users trying to connect to a single web server. It's something you'll have to play around with to find a value that works well for your app. The bonus with hanging requests is that the user gets near instantaneous notification when there IS a new event.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical [server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) problem.  Basically you have several options - polling, hanging requests, flash trickery - none of them particularly good.